LineIntegrate seemingly does not work
The scalar line integral function seemingly does not work, the both expressions remain unevaluated:
LineIntegrate[1/z, z \[Element] Circle[]]
LineIntegrate[Abs[z], z \[Element] Circle[]]

The expected result for the first one is 0 and for the second one is 2 Pi.
How can I get working scalar line integral in Mathematica?

Try
LineIntegrate[1/(x + I  y), {x, y} \[Element] Circle[]]
LineIntegrate[1/Abs[x + I  y], {x, y} \[Element] Circle[]]


Is this a bug?..

According to the document, the curve is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ rather than in $\mathbb{C}$.

For some reason, ContourIntegrate[1/z, z \[Element] Circle[]] works.

Of course, ContourIntegrate works on the complex plane. Perhaps you should read the help documentation more carefully.

Just Integrate gives the same result as LineIntegrate, so what's the difference?

Please read the Details and Options section of the documentation and be clear about what you are trying to compute. ContourIntegrate and LineIntegrate or Integrate calculate entirely different things.
